# MariaDB cant insert data with entity framework 5.0

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, mariadb

i have a problem with inserting data in my database.
I have three tables which i created with the heideSQL and linked the three tables with foreign key. 1st table (many to one) 2nd table (one to many) 3rd table. when i try now to insert new data with `db.SaveChanges();` it throws an insert exception which tells me that he cant match the foreign key because eventually two or more objects have the same primary key. but i just have one ID-Field in each table which is AUTO_INCREMENT. i use the ID-Field of the 2nd table to link in the first and the 3rd one.
could the problem be that everytime i create the new database object for insert that i always add the same object which belongs to the 2nd table to the db-object even it stays the same. same with the object for the 1st table. might that be the mistage and how can i fix this?
the code and the pic of the database are attached. i hope it helps to understand my problem.

Cheers, Only3lue

```
 db.zeichnungs.Add(zeichnung);
                db.projekts.Add(projekt);
                db.tags.Add(tag);
            }
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            } ...
```

Comment: Could you add more relevent code?

Comment: I found my mistake. I just have to add the projekt and tag only ones just before i call the db.SaveChanges(). Im adding the zeichnung in a foreach, so that i have many zeichnung, one project and one tag. Simple as that. But the other problem i have now is, when i try to insert new zeichnung data with same projektnumber and the same tag which already exists in database how can i update the connection from zeichnung to the two other tables? or when i add a new zeichnung with same projectnumber but new tag. how can i make all these new connections? any idea?